# How to observe two lists and compare them?

Tags: android, kotlin, data-binding

I am making an Android App, which generates a random four-digit number and must check input in EditText from a user and compare it with a random list. Can u help me with observing two lists? Can not figure out how to make it myself.

GameViewModel class and method which should observe Lists (didn`t work):

```
fun checkLists(enterList: List<Int?>, randomList: List<Int>) {
        if (enterList == randomList) {
            onGameOver(true)
        }
    }
```

GameFragment binding and button listener:

```
launchUI {
            val listInTextField =
                binding.outlinedEditField.text.toString().split("").map { it.toIntOrNull() }

            binding.listTextView.text = getString(
                R.string.list_num,
                randomList.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "")
            )

            binding.run {
                enterButton.setOnClickListener {
                    viewModel.checkLists(listInTextField, randomList)
                }
            }
        }
```

The problem is that i need not just compare hole list and value, but every number in it and it`s position.

Comment: The way you're doing it should be fine for comparing them. You may have a bug elsewhere. Use the debugger to step through the logic of the program.

Comment: @Tenfour04, thanks, i`ll try to figure out